# How to check if a string contains special characters (characters other than a-z 0-9 and _) with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I have a form where users write their username, and I want to check if their username has special characters in it. (characters other than a-z 0-9 and _)

How can I do that with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use character class ( **\W** ) which means anything except alphabets, digits and _

```js
const strArr = [`Dragon!"£123`, `Clown %^☻#52_`, `Fish_12354`]

let check = (str) => console.log(str, /\W/.test(str))

strArr.forEach(check)
```